# Char's bounding box order of vertices

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ocr, google-cloud-vision

Google Vision API documentation states that vertices of detected characters will always be in the same order:

```
// The bounding box for the symbol.
// The vertices are in the order of top-left, top-right, bottom-right,
// bottom-left. When a rotation of the bounding box is detected the rotation
// is represented as around the top-left corner as defined when the text is
// read in the 'natural' orientation.
// For example:
//   * when the text is horizontal it might look like:
//      0----1
//      |    |
//      3----2
//   * when it's rotated 180 degrees around the top-left corner it becomes:
//      2----3
//      |    |
//      1----0
//   and the vertice order will still be (0, 1, 2, 3).
```

However sometimes I can see a different order of vertices. Here is an example of two characters from the same image, which have the same orientation:

```
[x:778 y:316  x:793 y:316  x:793 y:323  x:778 y:323 ]
0----1
|    |
3----2
```

and

```
[x:857 y:295  x:857 y:287  x:874 y:287  x:874 y:295 ]
1----2
|    |
0----3
```

Why order of vertices is not the same? and not as in documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like a bug in Vision API.
The solution is to detect image orientation and then reorder vertices in the correct order.

Unfortunately Vision API doesn't provide image orientation in it's output, so I had to write code to detect it.

Horizontal/vertical orientation can be detected by comparing character height and width. Height is usually larger than width.

Next step is to detect direction of text. For example in case of vertical image orientation, text may go from up to down or from down to up.

Most of characters in output seem to appear in the natural way. So by looking at stats we can detect text direction. So for example:
line 1 has Y coord 1000
line 2 has Y coord 900
line 3 has Y coord 950
line 4 has Y coord 800
We can see that image is rotated upside down.

Comment: Had the same problem previously. Using character width and height seems to be a good idea. (Y)

Comment: As far as I could see from my results, the vertices are always right but the OCR itself did not find the correct orientation for the word. In my examaples I had images with simple text documents. But the image was rotated by 90 degrees ccw. Most words were detected right and the vertices are as expected. For some words the vertices were rotate by 180 degree and the OCR really "read" the word upside down (and got wrong readings).

Answer (score 0):

```html
You must to reorder vertices of four poins(clockwise inverted from A to D):
A-B-C-D that:
A: min X, min Y
B: max X, min Y
C: max X, max Y
D: min X, max Y

And save to your rectangle object.
```

Update: You can order vertices by distance from O(0,0) for A-B-C-D order above.